# What approach should I take to update provisioned / existing team sites

Tags: 2013, updatelistitems, provisioning, team-sites, update

I'm provision team sites based on web templates that are provisioned from a "request" list in SharePoint. (timerjob)

I know that there would be some changes to the team sites, but what's the best approach for updating already existing team sites? (add / remove wp, change views.. )

I'm thinking of give each library lists (documents, tasks..) it's own CT, and then update the CT from ct hub?

If powershell, please give some examples :)

Comment: How would you give a webpart a content type? I'm curious of that approach! I personally tend to make powershell update scripts, that do the changes needed to the existing webs, and run this script right before the changes are made to the "request" list functionality

Comment: Sry . CT on librarylists

Comment: Content Type Hub is always nice when working with content types, just make the change and publish the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CT hub is good idea, it is central location to control the things.

Here’s a little powershell to publish content types from the content type hub to subscribing sites.

```
$HubUrl = “http://contenttypehuburl” 
$HubSite = Get-SPSite $HubUrl 
$HubWeb = $HubSite.RootWeb
$Publisher = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ContentTypeSync.ContentTypePublisher($HubSite)
$ContentTypes = $HubWeb.ContentTypes
foreach ($ContentType in $ContentTypes) 
{ 
        $contentTypeGroup = $ContentType.Group 
        $contentTypeName = $ContentType.Name 

        $Publisher.Publish($ContentType) 

        echo "PUBLISHED [CONTENT TYPE GROUP] $contentTypeGroup, $contentTypeName" 
    } 
}
$HubSite.Dispose()
```

Note that after you run the script, you’ll have to execute the following timer jobs for the published content types to appear in your subscriber sites

- “Content Type Hub”
- “Content Type Subscriber” (for the subscribing web application)
  http://jtheblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/sharepoint-2010-powershell-content-type-hub-publishing-content-types/

this one having good collection:  http://sharepointfrancois.com/2013/04/23/collection-of-powershell-scripts-for-sharepoint-contenttype-cthub-sites-lists/

Comment: If I give a (task)library a CT. Then later wan't to remove a site column on that specific library. How do I "update" that specific CT to reflect what's in the ct hub